# How to predict event sequence with RNN/LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a system which generates event sequences continously, the event sequence looks like below in json

```
...
{'event_id':1001, timestamp:ts1, attr1:numerical_val1, attr2:categorical_val2, etc...}
{'event_id':1003, timestamp:ts2, attr1:numerical_val1, attr3:numerical_val3, attr4:categorical_val4, etc...}
{'event_id':1001, timestamp:ts3, attr1:numerical_val1, attr2:categorical_val2, etc...}
{'event_id':1005, timestamp:ts4, attr1:numerical_val1, attr5:numerical_val5, result:<success|fail> etc...}
```

Those generated events have common attributes like event_id, timestamp, attr1, etc, but also have event specific attributes as you can see in example. the events are generated in sequential mode, each event means something (sub-procedure) has happened in the system and the attributes in the event might be numerical or categorical indicating the performance or result. there is one specific event (assume it's 1005) which indicates the overall procedure is success or fail.

and the question is how to predict the potential failure (the label is uni-variate : success or fail) via the input streams of those events, including

- What model shall be used? I feel RNN/LSTM is a good fit for time series prediction, but not sure how it can be used for such event sequence prediction
- How to prepare the input data to be learned by RNN/LSTM? since the events do not always have same set of attributes

Comment: You can try to use tensorflow or pytorch to implement RNN-based network, https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent

Comment: I think so, but the difficulty I have is how to prepare the input data since those events does not always have same set of attributes. Shall I flat the events into dataframe with columns as below?

event_id(t-3), attr1(t-3), attr2(t-3),event_id(t-2), attr1(t-2), attr2(t-2),event_id(t-1), attr1(t-1), attr2(t-1),result(t)

each input will have only one event, but have to pad with all attributes from all events, thus it's very sparse.